# How to set BC for ViewController

Tags: swift

I need help to chnage color

How do change background Color for View controller ?
What is the code?

It is currently white .
Thanks
very Much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

This should work